# How do I impletment infinite scrolling for a blog app using RSS?

Tags: ios, rss

I was wondering if it is possible to implement infinite scrolling for a app that displays my blog's RSS feeds? Kind of like Instagram or Facebook when you scroll to the bottom it fetches more feeds. Can the same be done for an app using RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1):

Implement this UITableView Delegate method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And do a check on your datasource array count with the indexPath of the row.
Then add more data to your array with a custom method

Answer (score 0):

yes this will be possible - you will likely need to implement the logic for this yourself though.  Check out this post:

http://michele.berto.li/infinite-scroll-on-ios-with-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this component : https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh. There's a category which contains a method :

```
[tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
// append data to data source, insert new cells at the end of table view
// call [tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating] when done
}];
```

You can look at the sample, it provides you a pretty way to implement that.

Comment: Thank You for that! So is it possible to request for example 5 items of the feed each time the infinite scroll is hit? Instead of loading everything in the RSS Feed at once.